# how to update form that contains filefield without re-upload the file again in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

I want to update a record in my model, and it contains a file field, here is the form code:

```
<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'img'); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::activeFileField($model,'img',array('width'=>25,'lentgh'=>25)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'img'); ?>
</div>
```

and here is the update action in the controller:

```
$model=$this->loadModel($id);

$img = $model->img;

        if(isset($_POST['Press']))
        {

            $model->attributes=$_POST['Press'];
            $model->img = $img;

            if(isset($_POST['Press']['img'])){
               if(!empty ($_POST['Press']['img']))        
                  $model->img = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'img');
```

So if the user didn't upload an image, the value of img attribute should not be updated and the model should be validated, but I got validation error every time I click on save and the img file filed is empty, so how I can fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form validations are handeled by the model.
You can set an imagefield of filefield to be allowed to be empty like this in your model.php:

```
    array('image', 'file',  'types'=>'jpg,png,gif',
                            'maxSize'=>1024 * 1024 * 5,
                            'allowEmpty' => true),
```

EDIT:
You can check if the file is empty before overwriting the current value of the object

```
$imageUploadFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
if($imageUploadFile !== null){ // only do if file is really uploaded
    $imageFileName = mktime().$imageUploadFile->name;
    $model->image = $imageFileName;
}
```

Comment: no, if the field is empty, it will be saved as empty attribute in the db

Comment: How about validation? Do you have any? Imagine you have saved file path in the database and what will happen when you update the model again via posting the form without file selected? Validator will find $model->image is not empty neither file and make it null, no?

Answer (score 0):

You can use csenario as:

```
  array('image', 'file',  'types'=>'jpg,png,gif',
                        'maxSize'=>1024 * 1024 * 5,
                        'allowEmpty' => false, 'on'=>'insert'),
array('image', 'file',  'types'=>'jpg,png,gif',
                        'maxSize'=>1024 * 1024 * 5,
                        'allowEmpty' => true, 'on'=>'update'),
```

after that it will allow empty field on update

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue and here is my solution.

But first I will describe how I work with models.

**Basic POST processing**

```
if (Yii::app()->request->getIsPostRequest()) {
    $basicForm->attributes = Yii::app()->request->getParam(get_class($basicForm));
    if ($basicForm->validate()) {
        $logo = CUploadedFile::getInstance($basicForm, "logo");
        if (!is_null($logo)) {
            try {
                // uploads company logo to S3
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                // display any kind of error to the user or log the exception
            }
        }
        if ($basicForm->save(false))
            $this->refresh();
    }
}
```

and my `logo` field has rule `["logo", "file", "mimeTypes" => ["image/png", "image/jpeg"], "allowEmpty" => true]`.

This rule gives me freedom to upload or not to upload the file, **BUT** if I want to change another form field not changing the file it will empty the model's `logo` field and my database too.

**Problem**

> File gets empty if form update trying to update another form field, not file

**Why it happening?**

This happening because `file` validator expects `CUploadedFile` type of object when you have string in the model's `logo` field. String from database where you storing path to logo. And string is not `CUploadedFile`. And after `if ($basicForm->validate())` model resets the `logo` field to null.

**Solution**

Own validation rule which will upload/reupload the file if `logo` is of hype `` and do nothing if `logo` of basic `string` type. Here I will put a basic "in-model" validator, it is up to you to move it into separate class, etc.

```
public function checkFile($attribute, $params)
{
    $mimeTypes = isset($params["mimeTypes"]) ?$params["mimeTypes"] :[];
    $allowEmpty = isset($params["allowEmpty"]) ?$params["allowEmpty"] :false;
    /** @var CUploadedFile $value */
    $value = $this->{$attribute};

    if (!$allowEmpty && empty($value))
        $this->addError($attribute, "{$attribute} can not be empty");

    if (!empty($value)) {
        if (is_object($value) && CUploadedFile::class === get_class($value) && 0 < sizeof($mimeTypes)) {
            if (!is_array($value->type, $mimeTypes))
                $this->addError($attribute, "{$attribute} file is of wrong type");
        } elseif (!is_string($value)) {
            // we can die silently cause this error won't actually ever get to the user in normal use cases
            $this->addError($attribute, "{$attribute} must be of type either CUploadedFile or PHP string");
        }
    }
}
```

I called it `checkFile` and then the `logo` rule becomes `["logo", "checkFile", "mimeTypes" => ["image/png", "image/jpeg"], "allowEmpty" => true],`

That is it. Enjoy.

Note: I'm putting this here as an example. Code may not be completely correct, or used as is, all the stuff like that... :)

Answer (score 0):

I'had same problem. In my user model there wos a field containing path to image and i wanted to update model and fileField cleared my images.

So i figured workaround - **store field containing path_to_file** at start of action "update" in $tmp_variable and if there is no new upload - just set it before **save():**

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{ 
    $request = Yii::app()->request;
    $model = $this->loadModel($id, 'YourModel');
    $tmpPathToImage = $model->your_path_to_file_in_model;
    $yourModelPost = $request->getPost('YourModel');

    if (!empty($yourModelPost)) {
        $model->setAttributes($yourModelPost);

        $fileSource = Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot.uploads.yourModel');
        $imgTmp = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'your_path_to_file_in_model');

        if ($imgTmp !== null) {
            $imgTmp->saveAs($fileSource.'/'.$imgTmp->name);
            $model->your_path_to_file_in_model = '/'.UPLOADS_YOUR_MODEL_FILE_PATH_RELATIVE.'/'.$imgTmp->name;
        }
        else {
            $model->your_path_to_file_in_model = $tmpPathToImage;
        }

        if ($model->save()) {
            $this->redirect(['/admin/yourModel/index']);
        }
    }

    $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Hope it helps someone... :)